# Formatting dates with moment.js based on locale

Tags: javascript, momentjs, date-parsing

I'm using **moment-with-locales.min.js** for date manipulation and I need to format as the user leaves the textboxes. Because locales are an issue, I'm trying to use moment to do the formatting. However, I'm running into a problem and I'm not sure if I'm doing it wrong or what.

If the user types in something like '2/2/12' and I try to do **moment('2/2/12', 'l')**, using the 'l' for short date based on locale, it formats it into '2/2/0012'. That in itself seems broken.

If I try to format with **moment('2/2/12', 'M/d/yyyy')**, as seen in the JSFiddle below, it changes it to '2/1/2014'. It always bumps it down to the first day of the month and makes it the current year.

Here's the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b4ubd9a3/1/) I was using.

```
moment.locale('en-US');

var parsed = moment('2/2/12', 'M/d/yyyy');
if (moment(parsed).isValid()) {
    var d = new moment(parsed, 'l');
    alert('Pass: ' + d.format('l'));
} else {
    alert('Fail: ' + parsed);
}
```

I'd appreciate and help.

Comment: Why don't you just parse it yourself? It takes 2 lines of code, maybe 4 with validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `"D"` (`"d"` is *day of week*).

As for the year, according to the [docs](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/), «*Two digit year parser by default assumes years above 68 to be in the 1900's and below in the 2000's.*» so I'm guessing (and experimentation seems to confirm it) that if you use the 4 digit format (`"YYYY"`) it'll assume you are passing in the year 12 and not 2012. If you use `"YY"` it'll print 2012 correctly.

So, to summarize, the format `"M/D/YY"` should do what you want.

Comment: Though presenting a couple other issues, this led me in the right direction, thank you for the response.